# How to Edit or Delete an Appointment in Google Calendar with C#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, visual-studio-lightswitch

im just wondered if exists a way to edit or delete an Appointment in Google Calendar, im using Lightswitch to create the appointment like this:

```
public void SendAppointment()
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@email.com", "NEW EVENT");
        sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("no-reply@email.com", "password");
        sc.EnableSsl = true;

        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("invited@mail.com", "Invited"));
        msg.Subject = "Subject";
        msg.Body = "YOUR CONTENT";

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//GeO");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", START_DATE));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", END_DATE));
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + Direccion);
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
        //str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", msg.Body));

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", msg.Subject));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Reminder");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType type = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
        type.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        //type.Parameters.Add("method", "PUBLISH");
        type.Parameters.Add("name", "Cita.ics");
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), type));
        sc.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I dont really know how to get the specific event in a Google Calendar, someone can guide me to the right way?, thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the restful api: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/#Events

Use http://restsharp.org/ to call it